# Keeping rows based on source rankings in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this -

| Source Rank | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |

I want to make only keep the rows for each value with best rank. So the table will look like this -

| Source Rank | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | C |

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: The latest version

Comment: Sort the table on source Rank and use Remove Duplicates on the data tab using the value column as the one to check for duplicates.  It will keep the first version and remove all others.

Comment: @excel_noob: is your problem solved already?

Comment: @Dominique Yes! the comment by Scott Craner above worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to find a better argument for the invention of the "Subtotals" feature, as you can see:

[image]

Oh, in case you don't get the same results immediately: don't forget to click the <kbd>2</kbd> button in the left margin :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pivot Table from the source data, and set:
Row Labels: Value
Values: Source Rank - and use the pulldown to set to Min
Admittedly this will have the columns the other way round from what you show as ideal result.
[image]